# In-order Predecessor BST review

Tags: java, optimization, homework, tree

I was referred here from StackOverflow, so here is what I posted over there:

So, for an assignment, I have to construct a binary search tree, plus an assortment of related functions. I have them all working, but I'm looking for a way to optimize my way of finding in-order predecessors and successors. Here's my code for finding the predecessor (successor is, of course, nearly identical):

```
public double findPredecessor(double num) {
        if(this.has(num) == true) {
            node temp = this.root; 
            node iterator = this.root; 
            node returner = null; 

            while(temp.key != num) { //match the passed "num" to a key
                if(num < temp.key) {
                    temp = temp.left; 
                } else {
                    temp = temp.right; 
                }
            }

            if(temp.left != null) {
                return findMaxInternal(temp.left);  
            }

            while(iterator != null) {
                if(temp.key < iterator.key) {
                    iterator = iterator.left; 
                } 
                else if(temp.key > iterator.key) {
                    returner = iterator; 
                    iterator = iterator.right; 
                }
                else break; 
            }
            return returner.key; 
        }
        else return Double.NaN; 
    }
```

Yes, it is part of the assignment that my function take a double as argument, and not a node. I'm looking to see if there is a way that I can do this in one loop, to cut a bit on running time. I know that two successive, non-nested loops still is O(n), but still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CodeReview is a good place for this question....

There are a few things that you should consider...

### Style

`node` is a bad name for a Java class. Standards for Java are that Class names are CamelCase, and your `node` class should be called `Node`.

Using `==` to compare double values is often a cause of bugs. In this case I believe it is 'safe', but you should be aware that it is, in general, a 'bad idea'.

It is typical, though not required, that when you have an `if {.....; return ...}` block that you do not have an else block. For example, you have:

```
if (this.hasNum(...)) {
    .....
    return returner.key;
} else {
    return Double.NaN;
}
```

In this case the `else` block is not necessary, and it could simply be:

```
if (this.hasNum(...)) {
    .....
    return returner.key;
}
return Double.NaN;
```

Otherwise, the style is good.

### Logic

You actually loop through the tree three times. I presume `hasNum(...)` also walks the tree.

With problems like this you can reduce the problem to a single walk of the Tree.

```
node match = null;
node current = root;
node predecessor = null;
// walk the tree until we find our exact match....
// Our predecessor node will follow us whenever we take a right branch....
while (current != null) {
    if (current.key == num) {
        match = current;
        break;
    }
    if (num < current.key) {
        current = current.left;
    } else {
        predecessor = current;
        current = current.right;
    }
}
if (match == null) {
    return Double.NaN;
}
if (match.left != null) {
    predecessor = match.left;
    while (predecessor.right != null) {
        predecessor = predecessor.right;
    }
}
if (predecessor == null) {
    return Double.NaN;
}
return predecessor.key;
```

Comment: In the future, please refrain from posting complete solutions to [tag:homework] problems.

Comment: perhaps.... but his solution was accurate.. just sub-optimal

Comment: Yes, but it's also possible to guide the student towards a better solution without spelling out the entire code. Ending the review with a hint that a single-walk solution is possible would have sufficed. (It is, after all, an assignment, so the student should be able to figure it out.)

Answer (score 1):

@rolfl wrote a great review.  I just have a few minor comments to add.

The original code had a bug: if the `num` parameter refers to the smallest item in the tree, then a **`NullPointerException`** would be thrown.  @rolfl fixed that for you without saying so.

Your `temp` and `iterator` (or `match` and `current`, as @rolfl calls them) are **redundant variables**.  Only one is needed.

If you are doing the `hasNum()` check, then the way to do it would be to **return early**.

```
if (!this.hasNum(num)) {
    return Double.NaN;
}
// The rest of the code here
...
```

That way, you save one level of indentation, and eliminate the suspense of having to wade through a short story before reaching the `else` finale.  Anyway, it's a moot point, since you're better off not calling `hasNum()` at all.